# Handle partial data process inside for loops

Tags: apex

I have a method which is having a loop of Ids. Inside that I am calling another class's methods which is processing those ids one by one.
**Syntax:**

```
Class A{
methodA(set<id> idset){
 for(Id ids:idset){
  ClassB.MethodB(id);
 }
}
}

Class B{
MethodB(Id ids){
  //query on sobject based upon the id and other process
}
}
```

Now suppose if idset contains 10 ids and during 2nd id methodB gets failed then how can i process rest 8 ids inside for loop?

Comment: Note that your example suggests that you're indirectly doing a query inside of a loop (`methodB()` has a query, it is called inside of a loop in `methodA()`). That's just as bad as having a query directly inside of a loop, and you should strongly consider restructuring your code to avoid this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you handle failures depends on *what* part of the code is failing, and *how* it is failing.

For example, if the code you're concerned about is performing DML, and you're running into a validation rule, you could use the matching method from the `Database` class (i.e. `update myRecords;` => `database.update(myRecords, false);`). The second argument is a Boolean, called `allOrNone`. If set to false, your code will get 3 attempts to insert each chunk of 200 records (with failed records being removed between each attempt, and the successes and failures given to you as a `List<Database.SaveResult>`).

#### General method #1, Exceptions

Exceptions can offer a way to "gracefully" handle errors. They are thrown in exceptional situations where the code cannot be run any further for one reason or another. Things like dividing by 0, not having access to a particular field, a variable you're trying to use being null (which covers "argument cannot be null" as well as "null pointer exception"), etc...

They're generally meant for you to have a chance to write a log or send an email to notify someone that the failure happened. You *can* use exceptions as flow control (i.e. this record failed, let's catch the exception, do nothing with it, and move on), but that's generally regarded as an antipattern (i.e. a bad idea. Don't do it.)

#### General method #2, pre-processing your data

Since you're the one writing the code, you should have a good idea of what data will be problematic.

If you know ahead of time what situations will present issues, then why not remove the items from processing that will cause those issues? The preferred location to do this is at the start of your method. Get the work of determining good and bad inputs done upfront so that the rest of your method can focus on doing actual work.

```java
public void myMethod(List<Case> cases){
    // Instead of working on the input directly, we can pre-process it to remove
    //   things we know will cause problems (or only pass on things we know will work)
    List<Case> workingCaseList = new List<Case>();

    for(Case c :cases){
        // The 'continue' keyword tells us to stop processing the current iteration
        //   of the loop, and move on to the next iteration
        if(c.Subject.contains('this will fail')){ continue; }
        if(c.RecordTypeId == '[my bad recordtypeid here]'){ continue; }

        // After we're past the things we know will cause issues, add the record to
        //   the list of things we want to do further work on
        workingCaseList.add(c);
    }

    for(Case c :workingCaseList){
        // Do the actual, interesting work
        // Because you weeded out bad records before, there's less safety checking you
        //   need to do here
    }
}
```

This structure looks similar to a "fail fast" approach that you might use when creating an API (that is, you check to see if your arguments are null/empty and things like that at the start of a method so you can throw an exception before you waste time doing work that ends up being pointless).

There's an argument to be made that this approach makes your code easier to read. The valid/invalid decision is generally simple, and happens right away (part of a "self-documenting code" approach). The actual work that's being done isn't interrupted by safety/sanity checks.

#### Final note

On the Salesforce platform, you almost always want to be working on collections instead of on single items. You can certainly have a simple helper method that takes a single record and returns a boolean (which can help de-clutter `if` statements), but if you are doing anything involving queries or DML, then you want to be working on collections of records (and performing your query only one time).